# Find Value as Integer in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I would need a little help. If in the Textbox - TxtStringNum1.Text - we have the Digit 3. and TxtIntDraws.Lines (1) - contains the following set: `13,20,21,23,47,49,50,51,63,64,66,70`
It shows me that there is Exists a Digit of 3, but it is actually the Digits of 13. It fails to look for it as a whole.

```
Private Sub ScanareLinia1()
    Dim textsrtring As String = TxtStringNum1.Text
    Dim words As String() = textsrtring.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    ' Split string based on space
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    ' Use For Each loop over words
    Dim word As Integer
    For Each word In words
        For i As Integer = 0 To TxtIntDraws.Lines.Count - 1
            If TxtIntDraws.Lines(1).Contains(word) Then
                TxtResultStr1.Text = word
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ScanareLinia2()
End Sub
```

I have a good comparison code, but I do not know how to use it for the code above.

```
 Private Sub CompareNumbers()
        'Pentru funcția de Check-In (For Match Exactly Value Number in List)
        'First Textbox that is to be used for compare
        Dim textBox1Numbers As List(Of Integer) = GetNumbersFromTextLine(TxtStringNum1.Text)
        'Second Textbox that is to be used for compare
        Dim textBox2Numbers As List(Of Integer) = GetNumbersFromTextLine(TxtbValBeforeCompar.Text)
        'Union List of Common Numbers (this uses a lambda expression, it can be done using two For Each loops instead.)
        Dim commonNumbers As List(Of Integer) = textBox1Numbers.Where(Function(num) textBox2Numbers.Contains(num)).ToList()
        'This is purely for testing to see if it worked you can.
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        For Each foundNum As Integer In commonNumbers
            sb.Append(foundNum.ToString()).Append(TextBox25.Text)
            TxtbValAfterCompar.Text = (sb.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetNumbersFromTextLine(ByVal sTextLine As String) As List(Of Integer)
        'Pentru funcția de Check-In (For Match Exactly Value Number in List)
        Dim numberList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()
        Dim sSplitNumbers As String() = sTextLine.Split(TextBox8.Text)
        For Each sNumber As String In sSplitNumbers
            If IsNumeric(sNumber) Then
                Dim iNum As Integer = CInt(sNumber)
                TxtbValAfterCompar.Text = iNum
                If Not numberList.Contains(iNum) Then
                    TxtbValAfterCompar.Text = ("")
                    numberList.Add(iNum)
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next
        Return numberList
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following condition using [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) and [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof):

```
If Array.IndexOf(TxtIntDraws.Lines(1).Split(","c), CStr(word)) > -1 Then
    TxtResultStr1.Text = word
End If
```

So the following `Array.IndexOf(CStr("13,14,15,16,17").Split(","c), "13") > -1` is `True` and `Array.IndexOf(CStr("13,14,15,16,17").Split(","c), "3") > -1` is `False`.

Comment: Don't worked :(         If Array.IndexOf(TxtIntDraws.Lines(1).Split(","c), word) > -1 Then
                        TxtResultStr1.Text = ("0")
                    End If It does not show me anything in the textbox.

Comment: @MarioSandu - see the update. You need to cast the `word` from integer to string (here using `CStr`).